# Is there any code or service to add Watermark in pictures via Javascript on website

Tags: javascript, blogger

Is there any code or service to add Watermark in pictures via Javascript on website.

I am running my website in blogger and i want my pictures to get watermark. I have already added approx 600 pictures, and I can't download them and do via photoshop. Is there any alternative via Code , i can auto-watermark my pictures in my blogger site.

Pictures are hosted in Picasa.

Thanks

Comment: Even if there was such a tool what do you think would prevent me (or someone else) from sending a direct HTTP request to your server and get the non watermarked image? I thought that this was what you wanted to avoid in the first place, right? If this is so, you will have to modify the images on your server.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov Not necessarily. You would still have a car alarm even though someone could still break in and drive off with it. it's just peace of mind and it would deter most people.

Comment: Nothing, I was just mentioning this because the OP might be thinking that with this approach his car cannot be stolen. Because if you modify the images on the sever and not rely on client side scripting, they cannot be stolen. It's bullet-proof.

Comment: @Adsy, I think Darin is right, but still i will go with javascript, no issue with that.. Is there any such service or javascript code ?

Comment: True.
@johnsmith Your best and safest bet would be to use a program such as Adobe Lightroom. With this you can export a library of images with a watermark so you don't need to apply it to each one seperately.

Comment: but i want it to do with Javascript now. Editing 600+ images would kill me :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this one http://www.patrick-wied.at/static/watermarkjs/

but take care still any person can access the original  photo without water mark